# Question about Bases and Local Bases for Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Suppose $(X,\tau)$ is a Topological Space, $\mathscr{B}$ is a Base for $\tau$, and $A\subseteq X$. Let $\tau_A := \{W = U \cup (V \cap A): U,V \in \tau\}$. I want to show that if $x\in X$ then a Local Base
$B^A_x$ at $x$ for $\tau_A$ is given by:
if $x\notin A$ then $\mathscr{B}^A_x=\{ B\in\mathscr{B}\colon x \in B\}$
and
if $x\in A$, then $\mathscr{B}^A_x=\{B\cap A\colon B\in \mathscr{B}\wedge x \in B\}$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $x \in X$ and $W$ be an open set about $x$ in $\tau_A$, then $W = U \cup (V \cap A): U,V \in \tau$. Suppose first that $x\not\in A$, then it must be that $x \in U$. Since $\mathscr{B}$ is a Base for $\tau$ and $x \in U \in \tau$, $\exists B \in \mathscr{B}: 
x \in B \subseteq U \subseteq U \cup (V \cap A) = W$. Therefore, every open set $W$ of $x \not\in A$ there exists a Base element $B \in \mathscr{B}^A_x$ contained in the open set $W$.

Now, suppose that $x\in A$, then $x \in U$ or $x \in V \cap A$. First consider $x \in U \in \tau$. Since $\mathscr{B}$ is a Base for $\tau$ and $x \in U \in \tau$, $\exists B \in \mathscr{B}: 
x \in B \subseteq U \implies x \in B \cap A \subseteq U \cap A \subseteq U \subseteq U \cup (V \cap A) = W$. Consider now that $x \in V \cap A$. Since $\mathscr{B}$ is a Base for $\tau$ and $x \in V \in \tau$, $\exists B \in \mathscr{B}: 
x \in B \subseteq V \implies x \in B \cap A \subseteq V \cap A \subseteq U \cup (V \cap A) = W$. Therefore, every open set $W$ of $x \in A$ there exists a Base element $(B \cap A) \in \mathscr{B}^A_x$ contained in the open set $W$.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the confirmation, Brain!

Comment: You’re welcome!